# Remove Special NTFS permission from folder and subfolders

Tags: powershell, acl, icacls

Below code which I have for removing special NTFS permission

```
Foreach($folder in $path) { 
 icacls $folder /inheritance:d
 Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse | ?{$_.PSisContainer} | foreach {$subfolder = $_.FullName; icacls $subfolder /inheritance:d}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
}

# Check the existing rights
$acl.Access | where IdentityReference -Like 'BUILTIN\Users'

# Get a list of the rules to remove
$rules = $acl.access | Where-Object { 
    !$_.IsInherited -and 
    $_.IdentityReference -like 'BUILTIN\Users' -and
    $_.FileSystemRights -in 'CreateFiles, AppendData'
}

# Remove those rules from the ACL object 
ForEach($rule in $rules) {
    $acl.RemoveAccessRule($rule)
}

# Check that the remaining rules look good:
$recheckpermissions = $acl.Access

# Finally, set the ACL

Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $acl
```

This code is working fine for the ROOT folder (e.g. in my case C:\IBM), but it not removing the same for the subfolder under this. Please let me know what is issue here

Root Folder

[image]

SubFolder

[image]

Comment: The issue is that the subfolder does not inherit its permissions from the root folder (Inherited from is 'None' everywhere). Therefore, changes to the ACL of the root folder do not affect the subfolder.

Comment: @Theo: Thanks for your response. so in order to do this, what change we have to do..?

Comment: In your first loop, you turn off inheritance on every subfolder with `inheritance:d`. That may be exactly what you want there, that is for you to decide. However, by doing so, you will have to adjust access on every subfolder individually. You could decide to do that on the root folder once while inheritance is still **on** and later break inheritance. Again, I can't decide for your organization, that is all up to you..

Comment: @Theo: So until the subfolders are inherited, the code which I posted will not work..? our team wants the access to be removed, by any way I take. It will be great if you can provide some sample.

Comment: Indeed, that code won't work. If only because you are breaking inheritance from the root folder, and next (the code you posted is broken, because we can't see what else your foreach loop does at the beginning), because you never seem to instantiate variable `$acl` and start checking existing permissions using the _undefined_ variable: `$acl.Access`